# Dump network logs for internet explorer using command line

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line

I want to start automated test on internet explorer and before closing the browser, I want to dump the information in networks tab in developer tools to a file so that I can analyse it latter. Is it possible to dump the network logs to a file with command line,or using python?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no command line to execute the F12 dev tools.

In the Network tab, it can use `Ctrl+S` to export the logs as HAR, so you can try to check if you can use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to press `Ctrl+S` to save the network logs. Or simulate user mouse click to save the logs.

Besides, you can also use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to track the network traffic. You can check the logs in Fiddler anytime and it won't be affected by the closure of the browser.